# issue with self made random number generator in python. (using time.time())

Tags: python, math, random, time, numbers

I am well aware that python has a built in random library, so please do not include any reference to it in this. I am taking a do-it-yourself approach using `time.time()`.  I made a simple random number generator as is shown below:

```
def random(x, y):
    import time
    choices = [i for i in range(x, y)]
    t = time.time()
    num = int(str(t-int(t))[2:])%100
    xnum = [i for i in range(num, choices[-1])]
    ynum = [choices[i] for i in xnum]
    znum = ynum[choices[num-1]]
    ret = choices[znum]
    return ret
```

This works pretty well for anything like `random(1, 200)`; however, it has some issues. For example, if i were to do `random(10, 200)`, it would give an index error. How could I improve/change this to make it handle any two numbers?

Comment: Here's a hint: compare `len(choices)` vs. `len(xnum)`

Comment: You know this can only produce 1 of at most 100 results for any given values of x and y, regardless of how big the gap between them is, right? Most of the stuff you're doing with `xnum`, `ynum`, and `znum` is pointless.

Comment: @Hyperboreus He's just trying to learn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Random:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 20
        self.j = 1
    def randomBits(self):
        self.j = self.num * self.j
        self.j = float("0.%s" % int(self.j))
        return self.j
    def randrange(self,x, y):
         self.randomBits()
         return int(self.j * (y - x) + x)
```

Though, I did kind of "hard-code" it always being a decimal so I can use it like JavaScript's Math.random() I find you will like this one much better. I'm sure you know how to use it but here is some examples in-case you do not.

```
>>> random = Random()
>>> random.randrange(1,10**50)
20000000000000001525953968218377400658992994189312
```

So as you can see it generated a number between 1 and 10 followed by 50 zeros. To use random.randrange(numberOne, numberTwo) I hope this way helped you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have a function, say `randombits()` which generates a random integer in some range (i.e. 256 or 2^32). Then your `random()` function needs to first take the difference of `x` and `y`, i.e. the number of possible outputs of `random(x, y)`. Then it needs to calculate how many times `randombits()` has to be called in order to have enough entropy. Then it needs to combine the values of the multiple calls of `randombits()` into one long integer. 
One way to do this is to place output of `randombits()` into a separate digit of the long random integer, i.e. if the outputs of the calls are `8, 9, 1` then the long random integer will be 891.

Then it needs to scale down the long random integer to the number of possible outputs (the difference between x and y). One way to do this which `random.random()` uses is to keep getting a long random integer until it is within the range. Then it needs to add the long random integer to `x` and that should be returned.

Code:

```
RANDOMBITS_RANGE = 256

def randombits():

    return 4 # Replace this code with something that generates real random numbers

def random(x,y):
    num_range = y-x
    num_of_calls = num_range//RANDOMBITS_RANGE
    random_integer = num_range + 1 #So that the first time the while loop block will execute
    while random_integer >= num_range: #Keeps looping until random_integer < num_range
        random_integer = sum(randombits()*RANDOMBITS_RANGE**x for x in range(num_of_calls))
    return random_integer
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses almost the exact same logic as yours, but won't go out of bounds.  I understand that this is just for learning, but I feel the need to say that I would not use this instead of `random`.  Regardless, this code won't crash:

```
from time import time
def randomNum(x, y):
    #ensures the function is called properly, you can handle this however you'd like to
    assert y > x and x > 0 

    choices = [i for i in range(x, y + 1)]
    t = time()

    #ensures that the number is less than y
    num = int(str(t-int(t))[2:])%y 
    xnum = [i for i in range(num, y)]

    #ensures that you don't get out of bounds for choices
    ynum = [choices[i%(y+1-x)] for i in xnum] 

    #same as above + ensure you don't go out of bounds for ynum, too
    znum = ynum[choices[(num-1)%(y-x)]%(y-num)]

    ret = choices[znum%(y+1-x)]
    return ret
```

**NB**:
While this will not crash, it does **not** give pseudo random numbers, ie if you put in `randomNum(1,10)` you will not be able to generate 2,3, or 5.